# Python list sort weird behaviour

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x

Guys please help me to understand this weird behaviour that I managed to output.

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 3, 2]
>>> a
[1, 4, 3, 2]
>>> b = a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Why would "b = a.sort()" sort list 'a'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.sort()` sorts a IN-PLACE. This means that the contents of `a` are altered.
Further, `b` will be `None`

I think what you are looking for is `b = sorted(a)`, which creates a sorted copy of the contents of `a` and stores it in b

```
>>> a = [1,4,3,2]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> a
[1, 4, 3, 2]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
>>>
```

`a.sort()` will sort `a` and assign the sorted contents of `a` back to `a` (this is kind of what sorting IN-PLACE means). There is therefore, no return value (this is the same as a return value of `None`. So `a.sort()` is called, which sorts a IN-PLACE, and takes the return value of such sorting (which is `None`) and assigns that return value to `b` (therefore `b` is None).

If you were to do `b=a.count(2)`, `a.count(2)` is called, which returns an integer (in this case `1`). This return value is assigned to `b`, which is how `b` comes to contain the value `2`.

```
>>> a = [1,4,3,2]
>>> a.count(2)
1
>>> b = a.count(2)
>>> b
1
>>>
```

Similarly, when you do `b=a.sort()`, `a.sort()` is called (the call to `a.sort()` sorts the items in `a` IN-PLACE), which returns `None`. This return value is assigned to `b`.

Now, in the above example, `a.count(2)` still counted the number of occurrences of `2` in `a`, despite the fact that the return value of calling `a.count(2)` was not assigned to anything. This is the exact logic behind why `a.sort()` sorts `a`, even though the result is not assigned to anything

Comment: Thanks but I still cannot understand why "b = a.sort()" will actually sort list 'a'. If I typed only "a.sort()", I can understand why list 'a' was sorted.